# how to attach image from drawable folder to gmail in android?

Tags: android

I my application I have to attach an image from drawable folder to email client.
I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");

Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package.name/" + R.drawable.sample_1);    
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "some text"); 
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(url));
sendIntent.setType("image/png");
```